# More reliable alternative to Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: php, windows

I need my computer to execute a PHP script after every 10 minutes, for which I have used Windows Task Scheduler till now. However, it is not at all reliable. The code runs sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't, and I can't find any way to figure out what went wrong.

Does there exists a more robust alternative task scheduler?

Comment: I have found that with windows task scheduler some tasks will only run if there is a user logged on. Does the task run if you are logged on?

Comment: Building on what @vascowhite said: you'll need to take care that *all* the Scheduled Task options are set correctly. For example, some options default to enabled when you create a new task, including "run only if the user is logged on" and "do not run when the computer is running on bateries". (This last one can be trouble, because on a server the UPS appears as a type of "battery"... and and a server is almost always plugged into a UPS.)